# Best way to implement this custom layout

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, imageview

I need to do this in my app:
[image]

and so I need a way to put the `ImageView`, the `TextView` and the `EditText`.

What's the best way to do it? I thought to put all into a `TextView` but the size of this is too small and so it's not a good idea. 
I think also to use `RelativeLayout` but there are also other ways to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Show what you have done far.

Comment: @KNeerajLal it's another layout, I need that textview is much bigger than using the drawable I've posted far

Answer (score 1):

Everything is in horizontal, so I suggest to use LinearLayout. Inside it:

1. TextView with drawableLeft
2. EditText
3. TextView

Comment: I hate linear layout, it's possible to do with relative?

Comment: Why do you hate Linear Layout? ;) Of course, it is possible using RelativeLayout - you have to set "toEndOf" or "toStartOf" properties on your views

Answer (score 0):

As you see all views are horizontal so i suggest Linear Layout
and make orientation horizontal.
and use

1.use shape

2.text view
3.textview